# active properties not working using css and javascript without reloaded page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I apply active properties. but this not working using css and javascript.
I could click each any li then show active but not working.
please help me.
But should work without reloading the page۔

I apply active properties. but this not working using css and javascript.
I could click each any li then show active but not working.
please help me.
But should work without reloading the page۔
I apply active properties. but this not working using css and javascript.
I could click each any li then show active but not working.
please help me.
But should work without reloading the page۔

HTML code:
This is a HTML code all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sidebar.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="list">
            <a href="dashboard.php">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <span class="item">Dashboard</span>
            </a>    
        </li>
        <li class="list">
            <a href="sales.php">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <span class="item">Sales</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
            <a href="products.php">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <span class="item">Products</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
            <a href="customers.php">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <span class="item">Customers</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
            <a href="suppliers.php">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <span class="item">Suppliers</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
            <a href="sales report.php">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <span class="item">Sales Report</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("menu");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("list");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a all css code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

 .sidebar{
    background: #484848;
    position: fixed;
    top: 52px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 7px 5px 10px black;
}
.sidebar ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
/*    padding-top: 40px;*/
}
.sidebar ul li{
position: relative;
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
/*padding-top: 30px;*/
}
.sidebar ul li.active{
    background: gray;
}
 .sidebar ul li a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.sidebar ul li a .icon{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.sidebar ul li a .icon ion-icon{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.sidebar ul li a .item{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    white-space: normal;

    }
.sidebar ul li:hover{
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.sidebar ul li a:hover{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is a Screenshot like a this image.

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: It would help if you edited the text of your question into coherent, non-repetitive sentences.

Comment: "But should work without reloading the page" — What's the point of using links if not to navigate to a new page?

Comment: How does it help to mark the li element as active if you don't go to that page? Maybe you should not make them active on click, but find the active one by the current window.location.href

Answer (score -2):

To resolve your issue, Use the script provided below:

```
var header = document.getElementById("menu");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("list");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    if (current.length > 0) { 
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

The JavaScript code should be placed after the `<ul id="menu">` element.

Comment: Please **explain** what you changed and how your code solves the problem. Don't express answers in the form of a game of spot-the-difference.

Comment: "event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior" — `<li class="list">` is not a link.

Comment: HI TriveeCodez      It's work but linked not working href="dashboard.php"